# SQL Select Statement - Automation Anywhere

Tags: sql, database, csv, automation

I am trying to write an SQL select statement where i only extract two columns from a csv which has been connected as a CSV.

The select statement query i am using is:

```
SELECT * FROM [$FileName$.$Extension$]
```

Which extracts all data in the table as expected, I wish to only extract data in columns with headers:

```
Registration number, Date of last V5C issue
```

The below line of code throws a syntax error

```
SELECT ("Registration number", "date of last V5C issue") FROM [$FileName$.$Extension$]
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  The syntax would not work in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the parentheses:

```
SELECT "Registration number", "date of last V5C issue"
FROM [$FileName$.$Extension$]
```